# If/else based on the last character

Tags: r

I want to do an if/else on the last character on a string

Data looks like this:

```
Product:     
ANCHOR AEROSOL CREAM 250G - 2003726   
ARLA B.O.B SKIMMED MILK 2L - 7787579
```

If it has a L I want to put 1.03 in a column otherwise 1

So far I split the string out and cbind it

```
extra <- str_split(sains_part$Product, "-", simplify = TRUE)
final <- cbind(sains_part, extra)
```

But now I don't how to say if data ends in 'L' put 1.03 otherwise 1 and re-combine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of splitting the string you can take help of some regex. Get the character before `"-"` and check if it is `"L"` or `"G"` and assign values accordingly.

```
df$Value <- c(1, 1.03)[(sub(".*(.)\\s+-.*", "\\1", df$Product) == "L") + 1]
df
#                               Product value
#1  ANCHOR AEROSOL CREAM 250G - 2003726  1.00
#2 ARLA B.O.B SKIMMED MILK 2L - 7787579  1.03
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Product = structure(1:2, .Label = c("ANCHOR AEROSOL 
CREAM 250G - 2003726", 
"ARLA B.O.B SKIMMED MILK 2L - 7787579"), class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: thanks this is great and works.  I do not understand how it works though yet!

Comment: @MatthewAppleyard Break this down into smaller steps to understand. This first extracts the letter before (`-`) and compares it to `"G"` using `sub(".*(.)\\s+-.*", "\\1", df$Product) == "G"`, it will return `TRUE`/`FALSE` value for each one of them and then it assigns value 1 to value with `TRUE` and 1.03 for value with `FALSE`

Comment: one last thing, I noticed if it doesn't find a "G" or an "L" it returns 1.03 - is it possible to make this 1 instead?  Thanks again so much.

Comment: @MatthewAppleyard yes, we just need to interchange values. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `grepl`

```
df$Value <- c(1, 1.03)[grepl("\\b\\d+L\\b", df$Product) + 1]
df$Value
#[1] 1.00 1.03
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Product = c("ANCHOR AEROSOL CREAM 250G - 2003726", 
"ARLA B.O.B SKIMMED MILK 2L - 7787579")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If the two parts of the string are always separated by `' - '` and that character sequence doesn't occur anywhere else, you can avoid using special regex metachracters and instead check whether the string contains `'L - '`

```
df$value <- 1 + grepl('L - ', df$Product)*.03
```

Comment: My eyes hurt. Why not just `ifelse(grepl('L - ', df$Product), 1, 1.03)`?

Comment: No real reason, it’s just what I thought of first. In my opinion they're equally readable and your version is 34% longer (by number of characters).

Comment: Coercing to numeric implicitly seems an ugly thing to do, but I've also heard ifelse() is inefficient.

Comment: Interestingly, all three answers here rely on coercion to numeric.